# Como puedo hacer para que me imprima desde el primer bucle?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estoy aprendiendo archivos. En este ejercicio estoy pidiendo al usuario que digite cuantas veces quiere escribir una frase, hasta ahí todo bien pero cuando compilo no me deja escribir desde el primer bucle. Nose si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void escribir(){

int veces = 0;

ofstream archivo;
string frase;

archivo.open("Frases.txt",ios::out);

if(archivo.fail()){
    cout<<"No se puedo abrir el archivo..."<<endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout<<"Digite cuentas veces quiere escribir en el archivo: "<<endl;
cin>>veces;
for(int i = 0;i <= veces;i++){
    cout<<"Digite una frase: ["<<i<<"]:"<<endl;
    getline(cin,frase);
    archivo<<frase<<endl;
}
archivo.close();
}

int main(){

escribir();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema estaba en el bucle for :

```
for(int i = 0;i <= veces;i++){
    cout<<"Digite una frase: ["<<i<<"]:"<<endl;
    getline(cin,frase);
    archivo<<frase<<endl;
}
```

Debería de ser :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= veces; i++) {
        getline(cin, frase);
        cout << "Digite una frase: [" << i << "]:" << endl;
        archivo << frase << endl;
   }
```

Además té he eliminado la librería `#include<stdlib.h>` ya que pertenece a C y no la necesitas.

Código completo :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void escribir() {
    int veces = 0;

    ofstream archivo;
    string frase;

    archivo.open("Frases.txt", ios::out);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se puedo abrir el archivo..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Digite cuentas veces quiere escribir en el archivo: " << endl;
    cin >> veces;
    for (int i = 0; i <= veces; i++) {
        getline(cin, frase);
        cout << "Digite una frase: [" << i << "]:" << endl;
        archivo << frase << endl;
    }
    archivo.close();
}

int main() {
    escribir();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: No hay de que, lo importante es que entiendas el motivo por que cual no funcionaba tu código!